# Word2Vec Vocab Similarities

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, word2vec

I ran a word2vec algo on text of about 750k words (before removing some stop words). Using my model, I started looking at the most similar words to particular words of my choosing, and the similarity scores (for model.wv.most_similar method) are all super close to 1. The tenth closest score is still like .998, so I feel like I'm not getting any significant differences between the similarity of words which leads to meaningless similar words.

My constructor for the model is

```
model = Word2Vec(all_words, size=75, min_count=30, window=10, sg=1)
```

I think the problem may lie in how I structure the text to run the neural net on. I store all the words like so:

```
all_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(v)
all_words = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in all_sentences]
all_words = [[word for word in all_words[0] if word not in nltk.stopwords('English')]]
```

...where v is the result of calling read() on a txt file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `all_words`, just before passing it to `Word2Vec`, to make sure it contains the size and variety of corpus you expected? (That last stop-word stripping step looks like it'll only operate on the very 1st sentence, `all_words[0]`.)

Also, have you enabled logging at the `INFO` level, and watched the output for indicators of the model's final vocabulary size & training progress, to check if those values are as expected?

Note that removing stopwords isn't strictly necessary for word2vec training. Their presence doesn't hurt much, and the default frequent-word downsampling, controlled by the `sample` parameter, already serves to often-ignore very-frequent words like stopwords.

(Also, `min_count=30` is fairly aggressive for a smallish corpus.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, I recommend the following:

- Use `sg=0` to use the continuous bag of word model instead of the skip-gram model. CBOW is better at smaller dataset. The skip-gram model was trained in the official [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf) over 1 billion words.
- Use `min_count=5` which is the one they used in the paper and they had 1 billion. I think 30 is way too much for your data.
- Don't remove the stop words as it will change the neighboring words in the moving window.
- Use more iterations like `iter=10` for example.
- Use `gensim.utils.simple_preprocess`  instead of `word_tokenize` as the punctuation isn't helpful in this case.
- Also, I recommend split your dataset into paragraphs instead of sentences, but I don't know if this is applicable in your dataset or not

When following these steps, your code should be:

```
>>> from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

>>> all_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(v)
>>> all_words = [simple_preprocess(sent) for sent in all_sentences]
>>> # define the model
>>> model = Word2Vec(all_words, size=75, min_count=5, window=10, sg=0, iter=10)
```